# jQuery-UI doesn't recognize HTML5's hidden attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, hidden, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Using plain Javascript, it is easy to hide a select-menu option using HTML5's hidden attribute. But when I want to stylise the select-menu using the jQuery-UI, the hidden attribute is ignored. For example, define two select menus:

```
<select id="one">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option hidden>hidden option</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option hidden>hidden option</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>
```

Here's the Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function(){            
  $('#one').selectmenu();
});
```

When you run this example, the third item is hidden in the second selectmenu, but not in the first. It seems that jQuery-UI has disabled the hidden attribute. See

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvermees/xa4219ya/1/)

for a live example. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in jQuery-UI?

Comment: Your fiddle has no `option` element with a `hidden` attribute on it. (But if I [update it to have it](http://jsfiddle.net/xa4219ya/2/), jQuery UI still doesn't seem to respect it [at least not in that updated fiddle, using Chrome].)

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable.

Comment: why don't you use css class ?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I used jsFiddle. I forgot to update a forked example.

Comment: What did you find when you looked at the jQuery UI issue list?

Comment: which browser and version you are using?

Comment: Chromium 53.0.2785.143

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for the problem would be to remove them ,

```
$(function(){            
    $('#one option[hidden]').remove();
    $('#one').selectmenu();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsvdhsagar/xa4219ya/3/)

Comment: Calling this a workaround implies that this is indeed a bug in jQuery-UI? In that case I will raise the issue on GitHub so the jQuery team can fix it.

Comment: @PVM You are correct. I too was looking for better solutions and could not find any, has to be a bug .Better rise one and update here when you get a response .

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was a bug in jQuery-UI. I issued [a ticket on GitHub](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15098#comment:2) and the problem was fixed within 24 hours.